# Granting permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE issue?

Tags: android, android-fragments, runtime-permissions

After granting the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, it's not possible to write, only after an app startup is ok.I'm requesting it from fragment.Below the code to replicate the issue.

I'm testing in **Emulator 6.0**

```
 /**
     * Requests the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
     * If the permission has been denied previously, a SnackBar will prompt the user to grant the
     * permission, otherwise it is requested directly.
     */
    private void requestSDCardAccessPermission() {
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
            // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
            // For example if the user has previously denied the permission.
            Snackbar.make(mView, R.string.permission_sdcard_rationale,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            requestPermissions(
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                    REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        } else {
            // WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE has not been granted yet. Request it directly.
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        // END_INCLUDE(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    }
```

> onRequestPermissionsResult Callback

```
       /**
         * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
         */
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                               @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {
                // BEGIN_INCLUDE(permission_result)
                // Received permission result for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
                // Check if the only required permission has been granted
                if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission has been granted, preview can be displayed
                    Snackbar.make(mView, R.string.sdcard_available_permission,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(mView, R.string.permissions_not_granted,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                // END_INCLUDE(permission_result)
            } else {
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
        }
```

Just call

`requestSDCardAccessPermission();`

In manifest added

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>;
```

> More clearly, need to restart the app after providing
>   `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission at run time.

Error log:

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/storage/0E0F-380A/Pictures/2015-12-10-12-26-38-2090279097.jpg:
open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: "it's not possible to write" -- and your proof of this is... what, exactly? I have had no problems in writing to external storage after requesting this permission, without an app restart. You have no code here that writes to external storage, or any stack trace or other evidence of a problem. Make sure that your `targetSdkVersion` is set to 23 or higher, since you are trying to use the runtime permissions system.

Comment: Can you please checkout your code with `Emulator 6.0` the app getting crashed in fact when writing to the storage in same session without restarting the app.

Comment: And this is my code if you need to check out http://pastebin.com/HKHAaFqi

Comment: Since the error states "Unable to *decode* stream" (emphasis added), your problem would not appear to be related to this permission, because at this point, you are trying to read in the file.

Comment: And I'm only getting the error in Emulator 6.0 .i don't have a device other than this right now for checking. It's working in all other than > 23 .check this thread also https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2982

Comment: Yes . It's a bug of the emulator which I had used and they recently fixed it in latest version :)

Comment: FIX: Updating to the latest version resolved the issue.